# osx - Permission denied (126) using AppleScript with Administrator Privileges

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, admin

I am trying to run a script to enable the screensaver password on my mac (El Capitan), but it requires administrator privileges.  I am using an applescript to get the script to run with administrator privileges automatically, but I still get a 126 permission denied error.  Here are my files:

The script to activate the password (requires permission):

```
# ~/bin/passtrue

osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set require password to wake of security preferences to true'
```

Then I created an applescript to run that script with administrator privileges:

```
# ~/bin/trueapplescript.scpt

do shell script "/Users/user/bin/passtrue.sh" with administrator privileges
```

Finally I created a shell script to call the applescript file:

```
# ~/bin/change-via-applescript

osascript /Users/user/bin/trueapplescript.scpt
```

I keep getting the following error when I run the change-via-applescript file:

/Users/user/bin/trueapplescript.scpt:30:107: execution error: /bin/sh: /Users/user/bin/passtrue.sh: Permission denied (126)

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I have misunderstood what you are trying to achieve. But if you open the "AppleScript Editor" and paste in the following code, it should work:

```
set myAppleScriptAsShellScript to "osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to set require password to wake of security preferences to true'"
do shell script myAppleScriptAsShellScript with administrator privileges
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  That does seem to get it working.  It's strange that merging the first script with the applescript fixes the issue.  I'm assuming it must have something to do with security.